# How to convert SAS worddate format to Numeric Date

Tags: sas, character, numeric, date-formatting

My dataset has a character date column that contains date in August 15,2000 way.  I want to convert this to yymmdd10. format . i have tried following way and it doesn't work .

```
If not missing(new_date) then new_daten=input(strip(new_date),??worddate.);
```

Can anyone please help me. I have attached image of my dataset.[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x9Wj.png)

Comment: WORDDATE is a FORMAT.  You need an INFORMAT.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ANYDTDTE` informat](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n04jh1fkv5c8zan14fhqcby7jsu4.htm) to "read and extract the date value from various date, time, and datetime forms."

```
data want;
attrib date format=yymmdd10.;
input date anydtdte20.;
datalines;
August 15, 2000
;
```

Data in viewer

[image]